# Adding style to an array of react components

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styles, components

I want to add **inline** style to an array of React Components, anyone know how best to do this without adding the height directly into the 'ProductComponent'?

The component has three nested divs I just want to add the style to the parent div for each component in the array. I want to do this in a ScrollableList component which takes an array of ProductComponents. I want to add "height:33%" on each ProductComponent.

My 'ProductComponent'.

```
  class ProductComponent extends Component {
    render() {      
      return (
            <div
              className="productContainer"
              key={id}
            >
              <div className="imageContainer" >
                <img src={ImageURL} role="presentation" />
              </div>
              <div className="productDetails">
                <div className="productName"><strong>{Name}</strong></div>
                <div className="productPrice">£ {Price}</div>
                <div className="productBuyButton">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
      }
  }
```

I have an array of these components I'm using as children in another ScrollableList component.

```
render(){
  const array = this.props.children
  const children = array.map(ProductComponent => { 
     return(
      add style 'height:33%' to the div productContainer  
  }
  return(
   <div>
     {children}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to add inline style instead of just adding a class the has the style associated with it?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found what I was looking for in the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html).

```
{children.map(element => {
  return (
    <element.type
      {...element.props}
      style={{
        height: '33%',
      }}
    />
  )
})}
```

Allows me to assign style inline to each component in the array. 
An example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/tormod17/pen/apvXoW?editors=0010)

Comment: Best answer! Did exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If it's always going to be `height: 33%` or some other known styles then can't you just hardcode it into the component?

Like:

```
const product = (props) =>
        <div
          className="productContainer"
          style={{height: '33%'}}   // This should work?
          key={id}
        >
          <div className="imageContainer" >
            <img src={ImageURL} role="presentation" />
          </div>
          <div className="productDetails">
            <div className="productName"><strong>{Name}</strong></div>
            <div className="productPrice">£ {Price}</div>
            <div className="productBuyButton">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Alternatively you could just put it in your CSS:

```
.productContainer {
  height: 33%;
}
```

If you want to pass down the height from the scrollable list component you could do this:

Scrollable List

```
render(){
 return (
   <div>
     {this.props.children.map((component) =>
       <div style={{height: '33px'}}>component</div>)}
   </div>
}
```

Comment: I want to determine the height of each product in the ScrollableList Component not the ProductComponent.

Comment: When are you creating the array of children? Maybe you can pass in the height as a prop at that point?

Comment: I wanted to make Scrollable list reusable, and let it take a prop that determines the height of the scrollable window. so didin't want to add the scroll to ProductComponent.  This is the best I have so far.  
  
 `render(){
    const array = this.props.children
    array.forEach(function(ProductComponent){ 
   return (
    <div style=“height:33%”>
       <ProductComponent />
    </div>
    )
  }
 return(
   <div>
     {array}
   </div>
 )
}`

Comment: Edited to add another option - similar to what you're describing but more functional?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to send `height` down as a prop to each component and set a default of `33%`.

```
const arrayOfProducts = this.props.children;
arrayOfProducts.map((product) => {
       <div
          style={{ height: product.height || 33% }}
          className="productContainer"
          key={id}
        >
          <div className="imageContainer" >
            <img src={product.ImageURL} role="presentation" />
          </div>
          <div className="productDetails">
            <div className="productName"><strong>{product.Name}</strong></div>
            <div className="productPrice">£ {product.Price}</div>
            <div className="productBuyButton">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
})
```

This way when you declare the array you can override 33% with whatever you'd like as long as it is a valid `height` value like so.

```
const arrayOfProducts = [
  {
    ImageUrl: 'exampleImgUrl',
    Name: 'exampleName',
    Price: '$3.00'
  },
  {
    height: 25px,
    ImageUrl: 'exampleImgUrl',
    Name: 'exampleName',
    Price: '$3.00'
  },
]
```

If you were to use this data, the first `ProductComponent` would have a height of **33%** and the second would have a height of **25px**. Hope this helps!